# C#, ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework : user.cart items are null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. I have a class that handles SQL called `DataLayer`.

There is a `User` object in the `DataLayer`.

I built a function that includes all the cart's items and returns the user by id, then makes the user in the datalayer as the found user (so it could log in).

The function code is:

```
public User userWithInclude(int? userId)
{
    List<User> users = Users.Include(x => x.Cart)
                            .Include(x => x.Cart.shakes)
                            .Include(x => x.Cart.equipmentList)
                            .Include(x => x.orders)
                            .Include(m => m.menus).ToList();

    User user = users.ToList().Find(x => x.ID == userId);

    return user;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the function the logs in :

```
public IActionResult LogInUser(User vm)
{
    User user = DataLayer.Data.Users.ToList()
                         .Find(x => x.userName == vm.userName && x.password == vm.password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        User user2 = DataLayer.Data.userWithInclude(user.ID);
        DataLayer.User = user2;

        if (user2.Cart == null)
        {
            user2.Cart = new Cart();
        }

        DataLayer.Data.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

When I debug before the last line of the log in when I hover over the user object the cart's items all the vars exist but the object inside is null.

In the SQL Server database, the data exists with all the details.

How could it be?

Comment: Important side note: **NEVER** store passwords in plain in the database - use a salted hash instead!

Comment: Another side note: Avoid these `ToList()` calls. These will load all the users from the database instead of only the one you are interested in.

Comment: noted,  thank you . is there an answer to my question though

Comment: "when I hover over the user object" - if you mean the `user` object then it is clear, the cart details will only be in the `user2` object.

Comment: i mean user2 , sorry.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: I'm guessing that there is data in the database, but the query you're running is not the one you expect, and it's returning nulls. You need see what query is running and then run it directly against the database and see what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the get user class like this.

```
public User GetUserWithInclude(int? userId)
{
    return DataLayer.Data.Users.Include(x => x.Cart)
                            .Include(x => x.Cart.shakes)
                            .Include(x => x.Cart.equipmentList)
                            .Include(x => x.orders)
                            .Include(m => m.menus)
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == userId);
}
```

Then your login actionresult can look like this

```
public IActionResult LogInUser(User vm)
{
    if(Login(vm.userName, vm.password)){
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    // handle login failure
}
```

Make a seperate loginMethod

```
public bool Login(string userName, string password)
{
    User user = DataLayer.Data.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.userName == userName && x.password == password);
    if (user != null)
    {
        User user2 = DataLayer.Data.GetUserWithInclude(user.ID);
        DataLayer.User = user2;

        if (user2.Cart == null)
        {
            user2.Cart = new Cart();
        }

        DataLayer.Data.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this doesn't work you can try and get the cart after the user and debug if that's null, but I don't know enough about your foreign keys and relations etc to help you with that

Comment: Your answer is in fact an improvemt of the code in the question, but how does it address the problem the OP has?

Comment: @KlausGütter It makes it easier to debug for OP, and I thought the problem might have been with the.ToList().Find, if this doesn't help he needs to set a var or breakpoint on User user2 line and check what that contains. It seems quite difficult to help him otherwise because we don't know the class structure of cart etc. But if this doesn't suffice as an answer i'll delete I'm kinda new to stackoverflow I'm sorry :)

Comment: i already noted that i debugged it , the items in the cart return null but appear in the sql fully

Comment: @avihus Then it seems like it is a problem in your User or Cart class with a foreign key. Do you work with DataAnnotations or FluentAPI? You can try and create a `var user_cart = DataLayer.Data.Carts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FOREIGN_KEY_TO_USER == user.id);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use **`ThenInclude()`** method. You can get more detailed information from from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-7.0)

For example:

```
public User GetUserWithInclude(int? userId)
  {
      return DataLayer.Data.Users.Include(x => x.Cart)                            
                        .ThenInclude(m=>m.shakes)
                        .Include(x=>x.Cart)
                        .ThenInclude(m => m.equipmentlist)
                        .Include(m=>m.Orders)
                        .Include(m => m.menus)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == userId);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).